# Use SSJS in Custom Activity

Tags: ampscript, journeybuilder, ssjs, custom-actions

I was wondering if there is any possibility to create a Custom Activity that executes AMPScript or/and SSJS.

If so, how could I read Journey context information to the SSJS?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do with your AMPScript/SSJS?

Answer (score 1):

The SSJS activity can be used in Automation Studio or Programs, but it is not supported in Journey Builder Interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, script activities can be enabled by ET/SFMC support.  Technically you can interact with whatever objects are available using [AMPScript](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/) or [SSJS](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/).

Comment: Ok... How? I suppose SSJS must be executed from ET servers. What I don't know is what type of element I need to call in my Custom Activity definition to write some SSJS code.

Comment: Here's the SSJS Syntax Guide: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/

Comment: I know how to write SSJS code. What I don't know is where to write it to be executed into a Custom Activity in the Journy Builder.

Comment: If it's enabled in your account, there will be a `Scripts` section in Email -> Interactions: http://i.imgur.com/rX26OcD.png.  Once it's been defined, you should be able to add it to your Journey.

Comment: Yes, I have it enabled in may configuration. I can use scripts from Automation Studio but not in my Journey builder. Any guess?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs can you confirm that SFMC support can enable AMPScript/SSJS to be used as an activity inside a Journey Builder interaction? Or does this discussion around AMPScript/SSJS only apply to automation studio? thanks